# orderby lastUpdatedStamp in entity-find

Tags: moqui

I see we have a field in mysql workbench (and any other DB) named lastUpdatedStamp.
is it possible to sort the results of an entity-find using order-by tag and lastUpdatedStamp? (or maybe other solution)

like `<order-by field-name="lastUpdatedStamp"/>`

It's not working.

Comment: Can you post all of the code you have within the entity-find tags.

Comment: More details are needed to look into this... what do you mean by 'not working' (basic issue reporting: what happened and how different from what expected) and what does the rest of your test case look like?

Comment: StackOverflow is good for questions but this seems like more of an issue. For information about Moqui community infrastructure and how to interact with others in the community please see: https://www.moqui.org/m/docs/moqui/Community+Guide

Comment: ` <entity-find entity-name="oneOfmyJoints" list="mapp">
                <econdition field-name="onefiled" from="oneparameter"/>
                <order-by field-name="lastUpdatedStamp"/>
            </entity-find>`  this is how my entity-find looks like. I edit one of the records that is among the result of this. lastUpdatedStamp changes in mysql workbench but the order of the results of this entity-find doesn't change.I also added a dash before lastUpdatedStamp for descending order but no changes in the ordering of results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making a careless mistake as I was doing an entity-find on a view-entity with several member-entities.
I remember that it was possible to access a member-entity field by using:

```
<entity-alias>.<fieldName>
```

but it didn't work for me recently!!
So I fixed it using below line in my view-entity definition (alias lastUpdatedStamp field of THE intended member-entity )

```
<alias entity-alias="whatever" name="upstamp" field="lastUpdatedStamp"/>
```

then I was able to orderby like:

```
<order-by field-name="upstamp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Zaha I think lastTimeStamp is type of date and for date types order tag is like this :

```
  <order-by field-name="-createdDate"/>
```